# DotNetZip - How to save back to the original stream without creating a separate file

Tags: c#, .net, stream, dotnetzip

I'm working on a system where I have a Stream (which is seekable) that I am reading a ZIP file from, then am writing the modified ZIP file back to that stream. Doing so results in a corrupt file. This can be demonstrated using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Ionic.Zip;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
namespace ziptester
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OpenFileDialog mdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            mdlg.ShowDialog();
            Stream fstream = File.Open(mdlg.FileName,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            ZipFile mfile = ZipFile.Read(fstream);
            mfile.UpdateEntry("test.txt", new byte[500]);
            fstream.Position = 0;
            mfile.SaveProgress += new EventHandler(mfile_SaveProgress);
            mfile.Save(fstream);


            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void mfile_SaveProgress(object sender, SaveProgressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Saving_Completed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Save completed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Doing so results in a corrupt file.

So, don't do that.

Zip archives are a complicated format, they don't support read/write streams.

You will have to write to a new 'file' and when complete delete the old one and rename.

Comment: Performance-wise, this isn't the best solution, seeing as the ZIP file will be used as a virtual filesystem and will be written to frequently, and will be very large (over 50GB). Copying such large amounts of data at a time is not a good idea, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Saving 50GB of _mutating_ data in a zip file is not a very good idea, no.

Comment: Perhaps it would simply be best to write my own filesystem?

Comment: Or just re-design your data storage. Separate changing and fixed data, use real files/folders or maybe a (light) database.

Comment: Using real files and folders isn't an option, because the data I am dealing with is highly sensitive information, and storing it on a typical file system is not an option. It has to be stored in a single file, so an attacker cannot even determine how many files there are, and what the sizes of each file is. This is why an encrypted ZIP file seemed to be the optimal solution (we are using a seekable CryptoStream to read/write data).

Comment: Do you (or a hacker) need a key to see the file-structure inside a zip?

Comment: Yes. A key is necessary in order to decrypt/encrypt the file. By the way; should we continue this discussion on chat, as it is getting quite lengthy?

Comment: Instead of using ZIP files, I ended up writing my own filesystem. Ionic.Zip simply wasn't designed for such a task, although I have seen some Linux programs that have done this nicely, and actually allowed a ZIP file to be mounted as a file system. Seems in this case; it was the best time to "re-invent the wheel" though.